# Calculate time difference between two times

Tags: command-line, bash, timestamp

I've recorded the following two times in a log file which checks a reverse SSH connection ever 5 minutes. If the connection is down it records the breakage and keeps trying to reconnect every 5 minutes.

I want to calculate the difference between these two times. I assume the process is:

1) Convert them to a timestamp.

2) Minus one from the other.

3) Display the result.

```
BROKEN: Jun 29 16:15:01 IST 2017
RESTARTED: Jun 29 16:15:21 IST 2017
```

How do I convert the above to said timestamp? Or am I looking at this in the wrong way?

Comment: Why don't you save them in timestamp form?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basic way using `date`:

Extract the date from the line:

```
$ sed -n '/BROKEN/ s/BROKEN: //p' file
Jun 29 16:15:01 IST 2017
```

Convert to epoch time

```
$ date -d "Jun 29 16:15:01 IST 2017" "+%s"
1498733101
```

Repeat and subtract (I had some word-splitting issues with this date format, so I just command-subbed the whole thing. Maybe there is a cleaner way):

```
$ BROKEN=$(date -d "$(sed -n '/BROKEN/ s/BROKEN: //p' file)" "+%s")
$ RESTARTED=$(date -d "$(sed -n '/RESTARTED/ s/RESTARTED: //p' file)" "+%s")
$ echo $((RESTARTED-BROKEN))
20
```

The difference comes out in seconds of course...